# Install Exchange 2013 with DSC

Tags: exchange, dsc

I tried to install Exchange 2013 with the resource windowsProcess in existing Exchange Configuration.
All prerequisites are installed (the Exchange Organization still exists).

This is my Resource section:

```
       WindowsProcess Exchange2013  {
            Credential=$credential
            Path= "C:\Sources\Cumulative Update 5 for Exchange Server 2013 (KB2936880)\Setup.exe"
            Arguments= "/mode:Install /role:Mailbox /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms /TargetDir:C:\EX2013"
            Ensure= "Present"               
       } #End Filter

  } #End Node

} # End configuration

/*
  @TargetNode='TargetDSC02'
  @GeneratedBy=exadmin
  @GenerationDate=08/02/2014 08:16:03
  @GenerationHost=SOURCEDSC02
*/

instance of MSFT_Credential as $MSFT_Credential1ref
{
    Password = "Password1";
    UserName = "S05\\Exadmin";
};
```

Exadmin is a member of Orgaganization Management Group and it is also member of Domain Admin Group, to be able to install Exchange

When I execute this resource , Exchange Installation Start but after 1 minute the installation stops with this error:

> Failed [Rule:GlobalServerInstall] [Message:You must be a member of the 'Organization Management' role group or a member of the 'Enterprise Admins' group to continue.]

To be sure that the right is really the problem

I create a special User with only Administrator right of the Exchange server and with no Exchange Permission

I run manually on the new Exchange server `.\Setup.exe /mode:Install /role:Mailbox /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms /Targetdir:C:\EX2013`

And I got the Same error that with DSC.

After I add my test user in the Organization Management Group 
and I run again manually `.\Setup.exe /mode:Install /role:Mailbox /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms /Targetdir:C:\EX2013`

And the Exchange 2013 installation finish without any error.

That prove that the problem with DSC is Permission right.

Comment: If you're going to be doing this with DSC, check out [this blog series](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mhendric/archive/2014/10/17/managing-exchange-2013-with-dsc-part-1-introducing-xexchange.aspx) about the xExchange resource.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the first exchange server in a domain requires membership in the "Enterprise Admins" and the "Schema Admins" security groups in the domain, as described here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124778(v=exchg.150).aspx

The "Organization Management" role group is created by that first installation, so the schema will already have been prepared in your environment. For subsequent installations, membership in "Organization Management" or "Domain Admins" is all that is required.

Organization Management role group is described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124778(v=exchg.150).aspx

So yes, insufficient permissions would have prevented the DSC from completing successfully.